# Hazelcast distributed map: what is the default eviction policy?

Tags: caching, hazelcast

I have a distributed map in Hazelcast, something like this:

```
ClientConfig clientConfig = new ClientConfig();
clientConfig.getGroupConfig().setName("clusterName").setPassword("clusterPWD");
clientConfig.getNetworkConfig().addAddress("X.X.X.X");
clientConfig.setInstanceName(InstanceName);
HazelcastInstance instance =  HazelcastClient.newHazelcastClient(clientConfig);
[...]
map = instance.getMap("MAP_NAME");
[...]
// a lot of map.put();
[...]
// a lot of map.get();
```

I need to avoid OOM problems and clean the cache every time.

EDIT: It seems that the default policy is NOT EVICTION so it's necessary to clean the cache with some policy.
I tried adding an hazelcast-client.xml in classpath with this configuration

```
<near-cache name="wm_info">
        <max-size>3</max-size>
        <time-to-live-seconds>5</time-to-live-seconds>
        <max-idle-seconds>5</max-idle-seconds>
        <eviction-policy>LRU</eviction-policy>
        <invalidate-on-change>true</invalidate-on-change>
        <in-memory-format>OBJECT</in-memory-format>
</near-cache>
```

both adding this code

```
EvictionConfig evictionConfig = new EvictionConfig()
.setEvictionPolicy(EvictionPolicy.LRU)
.setSize(2);

NearCacheConfig nearCacheConfig = new NearCacheConfig()
.setName(WM_MAP_NAME)
.setInMemoryFormat(InMemoryFormat.BINARY)
.setInvalidateOnChange(true)
.setTimeToLiveSeconds(5)
.setEvictionConfig(evictionConfig);

clientConfig.addNearCacheConfig(nearCacheConfig);
```

but doesn't work... cache items still in cache even after some minutes.

EDIT2: The only way it seems to work is:

map.put(code, json, 5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

Any alternatives?

Thanks
Andrea

Answer (score 1):

by default eviction/expiration is not configured for map, you have to explicitly configure if you don't want your map to exceed a threshold. If you keep putting entries into a map with a default configuration you'll get OOM eventually.

Below is a map configuration which enables eviction with the policy *least-recently-used*. When map size reaches to the configured threshold, some of the entries will get evicted.

If you want to expire the entries too you may configure *time-to-live-seconds* and *max-idle-seconds* too.

```
  <map name="default">
    ...
    <time-to-live-seconds>0</time-to-live-seconds>
    <max-idle-seconds>0</max-idle-seconds>
    <eviction-policy>LRU</eviction-policy>
    <max-size policy="PER_NODE">5000</max-size>
    ...
  </map>
</hazelcast>
```

Take a look at the Map Eviction section of the documentation
https://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/3.11.2/manual/html-single/index.html#map-eviction

Comment: Thanks, I tried both adding the configuration in hazelcast-client.xml both in code (EvictionConfig and NearCacheConfig) but the cache items seems not expiring. I am using Hazelcast 3.9.2. Any idea?

Comment: you have to configure eviction for map-config (not near-cache-config) on server-side. I've added the relevant configuration to my original answer

Answer (score 0):

To add to what Ali commented, you have to add a size restriction of some sort on the cluster map side (number of entries, memory size, etc). Then you add an eviction policy to tell Hazelcast which entries to evict when it hits the threshold and needs to put in new values.